# Change Custom Post Type to Post + Category

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, categories, post-type, phpmyadmin

I have a rather difficult problem, I have a news site and I used a custom template with custom post-types for each "category" and now I want to change the template, but I can not change the posts for their respective categories in the post.

> Example: Post-Type - News Post - Category News

The most I can do is change the post-type of posts to post, but doing so all posts are left uncategorized. I need some plugin query that can change the post-type and at the same time allocate in their respective categories.

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### You can try this plugin see this

This plugin adds a simple post-type drop-down to the post editor interface, allowing you to reassign any post to a new post type. It allows you to switch post’s type while editing your post.

Post Type Switcher

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

The problem with this plugin is that it does not allow changing the category. I can change the post-type but when I do this all the posts are without categories and I have more than 25k posts.